# windows 2016 rdp sso displays other user login

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, single-sign-on

We have a Windows 2016 server where we want to add Single Sign-On, but when I add the server to the local GPO of my computer and try to log on, I get a screen with an empty user field.
I have tried both with windows 10 and windows 7 with the same results, for testing user I am using a Domain Admin Account.
I have also tried to add one of our windows 2012 servers to SSO with no issues.

I would like to know if anyone knows how to fix this issue?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself.

At some point I made a change in the registry, it screwed with the NLA settings for the remote desktop.

I made sure that the registry looks like this, and my problem was solved.

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\fDenyTSConnections = 0
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\UserAuthentication = 1
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\SecurityLayer = 1
```